# My nodejs&react js web application isn't running on aws ec2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2

I cloned my git repo onto the aws ec2 instance. My backend server is listening on port 5000 and my frontend server is listening on port 3000.
In my browser when I type in the url "ec2-public-dns:3000" the index frontend page is displayed (login page), however when I try logging in nothing happens. The are no errors in either one, yet it is as if they aren't connected at all.
I don't know what exactly could be blocking my frontend to connect to the backend apis.

Comment: Please check the backend API URL you are using in your application. Or try posting some more researchs or actions which you did, as some screenshots or some logs

Comment: My application is working perfectly on my local host. So the backend API URL are in check.

Comment: Can't help with this piece of information